# creating vnet and subnet using python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve the below using python sdk which i have tested from powershell .

```
$vnet = @{
    Name = 'myVNet'
    ResourceGroupName = 'CreateVNetQS-rg'
    Location = 'EastUS'
    AddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'    
}
$virtualNetwork = New-AzVirtualNetwork @vnet
$subnet = @{
    Name = 'default'
    VirtualNetwork = $virtualNetwork
    AddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
}
$subnetConfig = Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig @subnet
$virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
```

I have followed this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-powershell and tested the same from powershell but my use case is from python and i can't seem to find any relevant document or sample for it .

Comment: Hello @UserP, you have to use NetworkManagementClient for the case .. please refer: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.networkmanagementclient?view=azure-python)

Comment: Thank you for the response @AnsumanBal-MT . can i use only the virtual network operation to create a vnet and subnet like in a single operation without using subnet operations? if so , can you please help with a sample ?

Comment: yes i think you can create them in single operation as if you check the vnet create operations it consists of subnets in the virtual_network class in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.virtualnetwork?view=azure-python). let me test it in my environment and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can create virtual network  and subnet using the Virtual Network Operations only. I tested using the below code :

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.models import (VirtualNetwork,
                                       AddressSpace,
                                        Subnet)
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "subID"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_group = "ansumantest"
virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
vnet_parameters = VirtualNetwork(location='east us',address_space=AddressSpace(address_prefixes=['10.0.0.0/16']),subnets=[Subnet(name='default',address_prefix='10.0.0.0/24')])
create_network=network_client.virtual_networks.begin_create_or_update(resource_group, virtual_network_name,parameters=vnet_parameters)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

You can change the parameters as per your requirement , for that you can refer the below references:

> [VirtualNetwork Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.virtualnetwork?view=azure-python)
>
> [Subnet Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.subnet?view=azure-python)